# How to open two py files in different shells

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have a simple server program and simple client program
I store all my python programs in a single file i has around 30-40 py files (academic and online contest problems)
This time i created a sub-folder and stored the client and server files
when i run them simultaneously they open up in the same shell , i tried modifying code but no use,
later i got them back into main folder ....
this time they are opening in two separate shells

Why is this happening !Why programs in sub-folders are opening in same shell.

I will share my code also, Check if there any mistakes in it.

Client.py

```
import socket,time,sys
time.sleep(1)
s=socket.socket()
host=socket.gethostname()
port=12345
time.sleep(1)
s.connect((host,port))
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

server.py

```
time.sleep(1)
s=socket.socket()
host=socket.gethostname()
print(host)
port=12345
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
print('Waiting')
while True:
    c,addr=s.accept()
    print('Connected with',addr)
    c.send(b"Thank you for Connecting")
    c.close()
```

Comment: How are you running the programs? Are you executing them through an IDE terminal or something like windows command prompt?

Comment: python IDE terminal only